# C#, how I can get the members of a query-based distribution group ? (Active Directory)

Tags: c#, active-directory, console-application

I can't get the users of a query-based distribution group in a c# console application.
I was searching for some posts like this [C# Get Exchange Distribution and Dynamic Distribution Lists and their members](http://www.sghaida.com/c-get-exchange-distribution-and-dynamic-distribution-lists-and-their-members/), but I don't see the distribution group in the property "memberOf". In this property, I can see "Groups", but not "query-based distribution group".

Thanks.

**Solution**
[C# Get Exchange Distribution and Dynamic Distribution Lists and their members](http://www.sghaida.com/c-get-exchange-distribution-and-dynamic-distribution-lists-and-their-members/)

*Edit Class*

```
public class DistributionList
{
    public DLT DType { get; set; }
    public string CN { get; set; }
    public string FILORDN { get; set; }
    public List<string> Members { get; set; }
}
```

*In Main*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var distributionLists = GetDynamicDistributionLists();

    foreach (var distributionList in distributionLists)
    {
        distributionList.Members = listDDLMembers(distributionList.FILORDN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the article you linked, Exchange dynamic groups membership must be retrieved in two steps.

1. You must retrieve the directory entry for the dynamic distribution list so you can get the msExchDynamicDLFilter property.
2. You must use the msExchDynamicDLFilter property in a user search to find all users matching the property.

Answer (score 2):

*There are very few articles about Dynamic Distribution Group Search etc. on the web. Additionally the web page that pointed as solution looks dead unfortunately. Fortunately, I found lost article by waybackmachine tool and its content can be useful for people like me so I place it here;*

---

Below is the function which enables you todo so but before that we need to create a common class for both distribution list because they have something in common which is users who has email address. normal distribution list has members while the dynamic distribution list members is being auto generated based on LDAP Query.

first the common Class

```
/// <summary>
/// This enum will hold the type of a Distrinution List 
/// DL for Normal Distribution List 
/// DLL Dynamic Distribution List
/// </summary>
public enum DLT { DL = 1, DDL = 2 }

/// <summary>
/// This Class will Hold all the information about DL or DDL 
/// and based on the DLT it will call the designated function to return the list of email address
/// </summary>
public class DistributionList
{
    public DLT DType { get; set; }
    public string CN { get; set; }
    public string FILORDN { get; set; }
}
```

Then the code for every type of distribution list I hope that you will find a good use for that

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the List of A dynamic distribution Group in Key Value Pairs 
/// the key is the CN
/// the value is the filter for the membership of that group
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Dictionary of strings </returns>
public List<DistributionList> GetDynamicDistributionLists() 
{
    List<DistributionList> distrubutionLists = new List<DistributionList>();

    using (var group = new DirectoryEntry("GC://dc=xyz,dc=com"))
    {
        
        using (var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("GC://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dc=xyz,dc=com"))
        using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot, "(ObjectClass=msExchDynamicDistributionList)"))
        using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                if (result.Properties.Contains("cn") && result.Properties.Contains("msExchDynamicDLFilter"))
                {
                    DistributionList dl = new DistributionList();
                    
                    dl.DType = DLT.DDL;
                    dl.CN = result.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();
                    dl.FILORDN = result.Properties["msExchDynamicDLFilter"][0].ToString();

                    distrubutionLists.Add(dl); 
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return distrubutionLists;

}

/// <summary>
/// Get the List of A distribution Group in Key Value Pairs
/// the key is the CN
/// the value is the DN of the Group
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Dictionary of strings</returns>
public List<DistributionList> GetDistributionLists() 
{
    List<DistributionList> distrubutionLists = new List<DistributionList>();

    using (var group = new DirectoryEntry("GC://dc=xyz,dc=com"))
    {

        using (var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("GC://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dc=xyz,dc=com"))
        using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot, "(&(objectCategory=group)(!groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648))"))
        using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                if (result.Properties.Contains("cn") && result.Properties.Contains("distinguishedName"))
                {
                    DistributionList dl = new DistributionList();
                    
                    dl.DType = DLT.DL;
                    dl.CN = result.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();
                    dl.FILORDN = result.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();

                    distrubutionLists.Add(dl);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return distrubutionLists;
}

/// <summary>
/// List Distribution List Members
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dn"> The distinguishedName of the Group </param>
/// <returns>List of Email Addresses</returns>
public List<string> listDLMembers(string dn) 
{
    List<string> addresses = new List<string>();

    using (var group = new DirectoryEntry("GC://dc=xyz,dc=com"))
    {

        using (var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("GC://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dc=xyz,dc=com"))
        using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot, "(&(objectCategory=person)(|(objectClass=contact)(objectClass=user))(memberOf=" + dn + "))"))
        using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                if (result.Properties.Contains("mail"))
                    addresses.Add(result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    return addresses;
}

/// <summary>
/// List Dynamic Distribution List Members
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filter"> Filter to be used in the LDAP Query</param>
/// <returns>List Of Email Addresses</returns>
public  List<string>  listDDLMembers(string filter) 
{
   // The filter is the value of the previous dictionary

    List<string> addresses = new List<string>();

    using (var group = new DirectoryEntry("GC://dc=xyz,dc=com"))
    {

        using (var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("GC://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dc=xyz,dc=com"))
        using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot, filter))
        using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                if (result.Properties.Contains("mail"))
                    addresses.Add(result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    return addresses;
}
```

---

And a little conversation under the article;

### Q

> In your method listDDLMembers what would the ldap query look like?
> I’ve tried all kinds of examples with no success.
>
> Basically what I need is to determine if a user is in a particular
> dynamic distribution list, I have the distribution list attributes and
> can search on anything, I’m just having trouble cobbling together the
> actual query.

### A

> the filter or DN will be the out put of

```
GetDynamicDistributionLists
```

> which I’m publishing using an object called

```
DistributionList
```

> and it will look something like this

```
(&(extensionAttribute3=xxx)(mailNickname=*)(!(name=SystemMailbox{*))(!(name=CAS_{*))(!(msExchRecipientTypeDetails=16777216))(!(msExchRecipientTypeDetails=536870912))(!(msExchRecipientTypeDetails=8388608)))
```